# PHP mailing only work with my servermail

Tags: php, email, server, apache2, issue-tracking

I've already check link on stackoverflow and i did not find answer.

My issue is :

I have a website with a contact page.
It takes the following fields :

- Name
- Email
- Subject
- Message

When i click on submit, i get an email only if the email address is that of my personnal server.

I use apache2, php7.0.

I don't how to fix this issue and always send contact mail with my private adress.

Sorry for my english and thanks for answering !

Thibaud

Comment: How do you mail? Can you try to delete the From header?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: If i delete the from header, i don't receive any mail... 
What do you think if i hardcode the working email address and if i add the email sender to the message ?

Thanks for answering

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi I'll post my code later in the evenning.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: It is not answered yet. Once we all will be having a look at your code, then only it will be possible for us to suggest the answer. Waiting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : 
Problem in the variable instanciation in my code.